# Validation error DOCTYPE HTML

Tags: html, doctype

I'm trying to validate my own code right now. I got the error

"no document type declaration; implying "< !DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>""

When i put < DOCTYPE> at the beginning of my code, i get errors for the "&nbsp" i used in my code. i used "&nbsp" to align my numbers.

Is there another code for just SPACE?

this is the outline of my code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...... </title>
</head>
<body>............</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: can you please show us the full code? Also what validation service did you use? The html template that you have provided is pretty useless.

Comment: i used http://validator.w3.org/.

Comment: Exactly how did you submit your document to the validator? It defaults to HTML 4.01 Transitional or XHTML 1.0 Transitional, depending on content type, so you must have done something special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there another code for just SPACE?**

Yes. Try `&#160;` instead of `&nbsp;`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<body>
<div>Just testing&#160;&#160;space</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/maVTU/1/)

Comment: i have to use standard HTML 4.01 btw

Comment: I got it. i had to put <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

Comment: The references `&#160;` and `&nbsp;` both stand for NON-BREAKKING SPACE U+00A0, not SPACE U+0020, and in HTML syntax, they are completely equivalent, so replacing `&nsbp;` by the more cryptic numeric reference does not help.

Answer (score 0):

ensure you have a `;` at the end of `&nbsp` so it's `&nbsp;`

Comment: didnt work, i got this message now. " reference to entity "nbsp" for which no system identifier could be generated"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<body>
</body>
```

and you can learn more about DOCTYPE [here](http://www.totalvalidator.com/support/doctypes.html)